# Extracting multi values to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, extract

I have a raster layer with pixel values of 1 and 0. I would like to extract values from several other, overlaying, raster layers for all the cells that equal 1.

Is there any ArcMap tool similar to *extract multi values to point* that I could use?

Comment: Perhaps Con is what you're after though it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.. do you have a binary (1-0) raster for each of the several rasters you wish to extract the values from? Can you expand on what rasters you have and what your intended result is. Also it's *really* important when dealing with ArcGIS and rasters to state whether you have access to extensions and which ones; The most important is Spatial Analyst but in some cases 3d Analyst is required or useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you want is called the [**Sample Tool**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/sample.htm). It requires the Spatial Analyst extension. The input location can be a raster or point features. I've never tried it with a raster, but it should work with what you have. However, you will need to convert your zero values to Null first using the [**SetNull**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) tool.

From the documentation:

> *When the input location is a raster, the set of location cells
>   consists of all cells that have a value of zero or greater. Cells that
>   have NoData values are not included in the location set. A location
>   raster can be easily created using the extraction tools.*

and

> *When the location input is raster, for best results, the cell size and
>   registration of the input rasters and the location raster should be
>   the same.*

You can input your other rasters and the output will be a table with attributes from values at all your 1 values.

More about how the Sample Tool works [**here**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-how-sample-works.htm).

Comment: Hi Fezter, thanks a lot for your help. The sample tool was exactly what I was looking for. I used the Set Null tool first as you suggested and it worked perfectly.